# What are the pre-requisites to NFS Mount in between two servers?

Tags: networking, nfs, mount, prerequisites

I understand port 111 and port 2049 needs to be accessible; but what are the other pre-requisite that's needed to be present before being able to NFS Mount?

We have tried NFS Mount using "mount -v -t nfs : " and still there's no response or reply despite the verbose switch.

Appreciate steps of troubleshooting, be it network or system.

Comment: `tcpdump` is my first port of call.

Comment: Thanks for answering. For the benefit of beginners like me; can you help describe how I could use tcpdump?

Comment: Questions go in questions, not comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NFS requires PRC to be working first, thus you will need to have the RPC service running first, then you will need to run the mountd daemon to listen for NFS mount calls.  RPC calls are most often UDP calls thus you will need to ensure your firewall is configured to handle UDP connection tracking.  It is possible to configure NFS to use TCP, check your vendor's documentation for more information.

[Chapter 12](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/ch-nfs.html) of the RHEL 6 documentation provides a fair bit of useful documentation.